# Call change event of an input programatically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to programatically trigger the onchange event of an input that has the source below :

```
<input class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" id="f1d5fcd30110a5c" aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" value="">
```

I can see on devtools this input has a change listener attached, as you can see on the image at the end of the question. What i'm trying to do is call this event programatically, using the code below :

```
document.getElementById('f1d5fcd30110a5c').onchange();
```

But i get the error :

```
VM834:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onchange is not a function
```

How can i trig the attached event listener programatically using JS ?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @delphirules If the event handler you are trying to call was added using `addEventListener` the `onchange` property would  be `null`. So you need to dispatch the event. The linked  question describes how  to.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thank you , i see the element.dispatchEvent method; do you know how do i send the change event passing parameters ?